# nginx rewrite = HTTP301 always?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, amazon-elb

I've got an instance sitting behind an AWS Application Load Balancer and configured as a member of that ALB's TargetGroup is the healthcheck URL that is performed against the instance.

My current nginx server block permits calls to /folder/page which resolves to /folder/page.php.

```
 server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        keepalive_timeout 70;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;

        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
            # call .php scripts without their extension
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
```

When the ELB performs a healthcheck using the URL `/healthCheckTest` (that folder has an index.php in it) the healthcheck fails with an HTTP 301 response (I've configured the check to only accept HTTP 200 results). When I configure the healthcheck URL as `/healthCheckTest/`, it passes (I assume because of the `index index.php` directive).

I'm *reasonably* new to nginx and, to be honest, I never tried Apache2 with the rewrite behind an ELB, but I wondered if all rewrites perform an HTTP redirect (either permanent or not) but is this normal behavior? I've been trying a number of alternatives and nothing seems to work - possibly because a rewrite in nginx is synonymous with an HTTP 301?

Is my only option to make the healthcheck accept HTTP301 as well as HTTP200?

Comment: Try adding: `location = /healthCheckTest { rewrite ^ /healthCheckTest/ last; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith that's good for this one instance, but what about other folders? `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` should work for this, surely?